# How to prevent a celery task from running twice?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am running a django application with celery to run a periodic task that should run once per day, but the problem is it's running twice a day.

My task inherits from the PeriodicTask class and uses the following property to run once day :

> run_every = crontab(hour=1, minute=1)

We have two queues:

- slow_queue
- fast_queue

In my CELERY_ROUTES variable, I do not assign the task to a queue.

We also have two celery workers defined as shown.  Both explicitly mention the slow_queue.

Do I need to explicitly route my task to a queue, using the CELERY_ROUTES variable to prevent it from being executed twice?

> celeryworker:
> image: ${REGISTRY}/random-django-project:${TAGNAME}

> ```
> command: celery worker -A config.celery_config -l ${LOGLEVEL} -X slow_queue --hostname=worker@%h -O fair --autoscale=12,4
> privileged: true
> env_file: env.${ENVIRONMENT}
> restart: unless-stopped
> labels:
>   tier: backend
>   io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: tier=backend
>   io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
> ```
>
> celeryworker-slow:
> image: ${REGISTRY}/random-django-project:${TAGNAME}

> ```
> command: celery worker -A config.celery_config -l ${LOGLEVEL} -Q slow_queue --hostname=worker-slow@%h -O fair --autoscale=12,4
> privileged: true
> env_file: env.${ENVIRONMENT}
> restart: unless-stopped
> labels:
>   tier: backend
>   io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: tier=backend
>   io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
> ```